# Problems writing Scraped data to csv with Slavic characters (UnicodeEncodeError & TypeError)

Tags: python, csv, encoding, utf-8, scrapy

**Intention / Wanted result:**

To scrape the link titles (i.e. the text of the links with each item) from a Czech website:

https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vypis/nabidka-prodej/byt/praha

And print out the result in a CSV file. Preferably in a list so that I can later manipulate the data in another Python Data analytics model.

**Result / Problem:**

I am getting an UnicodeEncodeError and a TypeError. I suspect this has to do with the non-normal characters that exist in the Czech Language. Please see below for traceback.

**Traceback:**

TypeError Traceback:

```
2017-01-19 08:00:18 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'title': b'\n                                Ob\xc4\x9bt\xc3\xad 6. kv\xc4\x9b'
          b'tna, Praha - Kr\xc4\x8d                            '}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\phili\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 651, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\phili\Documents\Python Scripts\Scrapy Spiders\bezrealitky\bezrealitky\pipelines.py", line 24, in process_item
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
  File "C:\Users\phili\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\exporters.py", line 193, in export_item
    self._write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export(item)
  File "C:\Users\phili\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\exporters.py", line 217, in _write_headers_and_set_fields_to_export
    self.csv_writer.writerow(row)
  File "C:\Users\phili\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\codecs.py", line 718, in write
    return self.writer.write(data)
  File "C:\Users\phili\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\codecs.py", line 376, in write
    data, consumed = self.encode(object, self.errors)
TypeError: Can't convert 'bytes' object to str implicitly
```

UnicodeEncodeError Traceback:

```
2017-01-19 08:00:18 [scrapy] ERROR: Error processing {'title': b'\n                                Ob\xc4\x9bt\xc3\xad 6. kv\xc4\x9b'
          b'tna, Praha - Kr\xc4\x8d                            '}
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\phili\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\twisted\internet\defer.py", line 651, in _runCallbacks
    current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
  File "C:\Users\phili\Documents\Python Scripts\Scrapy Spiders\bezrealitky\bezrealitky\pipelines.py", line 24, in process_item
    self.exporter.export_item(item)
  File "C:\Users\phili\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\site-packages\scrapy\exporters.py", line 198, in export_item
    self.csv_writer.writerow(values)
  File "C:\Users\phili\Anaconda3\envs\py35\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 19, in encode
    return codecs.charmap_encode(input,self.errors,encoding_table)[0]
UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\u011b' in position 37: character maps to <undefined>
```

**Situation / Process:**

I am running the scrapy crawl bezrealitky (i.e. name of spider). I have configured the pipeline with a CSVItemExporter I found on the internet, and tried to adapt it to UTF-8 encode when opening the file (I also tried in the beginning without adding UTF-8, but same error).

**My pipeline code:**

```
from scrapy.conf import settings
from scrapy.exporters import CsvItemExporter
import codecs


class CsvPipeline(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.file = codecs.open("booksdata.csv", 'wb', encoding='UTF-8')
        self.exporter = CsvItemExporter(self.file)
        self.exporter.start_exporting()

    def close_spider(self, spider):
        self.exporter.finish_exporting()
        self.file.close()

    def process_item(self, item, spider):
        self.exporter.export_item(item)
        return item
```

**My settings file:**

```
BOT_NAME = 'bezrealitky'

SPIDER_MODULES = ['bezrealitky.spiders']
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = 'bezrealitky.spiders'

# Configure item pipelines
# See http://scrapy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
    'bezrealitky.pipelines.CsvPipeline': 300,
```

**My spider code:**

```
class BezrealitkySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bezrealitky'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vypis/nabidka-prodej/byt/praha'
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        item = BezrealitkyItem()
        items = []
        for records in response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class,"record")]'):
            item['title'] = response.xpath('.//div[@class="details"]/h2/a[@href]/text()').extract()[1].encode('utf-8')
            items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

**Solutions tried so far:**

- To add and remove .encode('utf-8) to the extract() command, and also in the pipeline.py but it didn't work.
- Also tried adding # -*- coding: utf-8 -*- to the beginning, didn't work either
- I tried to change the python code to utf-8 in the console with this:

  chcp 65001

  set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf-8

**Conclusion:**

I am cannot get the scraped data to write to the CSV file, the CSV is created but there is nothing in it. Even though in the shell I can see that data is scraped but it isn't decoded / encoded properly and throws an error before it is writte to file.

I am complete beginner with this, just trying to pick up Scrapy. Would really appreciate any help I can get!

Comment: is it working without `-o test.csv -t csv`? also, are you writing something to a file? maybe in your pipeline?

Comment: You'll need to include the *full traceback*. It depends on the context as to what the solution should be. Adding the `coding` comment only applies to **decoding** string literals in source code, so that won't apply here.Setting your console to codepage 65001 only applies to *printing* (writing to `sys.stdout`), but I see no print statements.

Comment: @eLRuLL, yes it works without the output to CSV, it is somehow only when I try to output it to the CSV file that I hit the UnicodeEncodeError. Interesting fact is that when I use the scrapy shell I get the perfect text, i.e. incl. slavic characters. When I see the output from the spider in the shell (i.e. without the CSV export), then it is in unicode...

Comment: @MartijnPieters very sorry, I updated the question and I hope it is clearer now when I run into for problems. Please let me know if something needs further clarification!

Comment: You are writing Unicode values to a CSV file, but in Python 2, the `csv` module can't handle Unicode. You can't use `codecs.open()` with the `csv` module, and you *have* to encode before passing in values. Use `self.file = open("booksdata.csv", 'wb')` at the very least. I'm not familiar enough with Scrapy to give advice on where to encode your scraped data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I use in order to scrape Czech websites and avoid this errors is [unidecode](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/Unidecode) module. What this module does is an ASCII transliterations of Unicode text.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from unidecode import unidecode

class BezrealitkySpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'bezrealitky'
    start_urls = [
        'https://www.bezrealitky.cz/vypis/nabidka-prodej/byt/praha'
    ]
    def parse(self, response):
        item = BezrealitkyItem()
        items = []
        for records in response.xpath('//*[starts-with(@class,"record")]'):
            item['title'] = unidecode(response.xpath('.//div[@class="details"]/h2/a[@href]/text()').extract()[1].encode('utf-8'))
            items.append(item)
        return(items)
```

Since I use an [ItemLoader](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/loaders.html#declaring-item-loaders) my code look kind of like this:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
from scrapy.loader import ItemLoader

class BaseItemLoader(ItemLoader):
    title_in = MapCompose(unidecode)
```

Comment: Thanks for this! It works with the Slavic character error, now I have a Item Loader problem instead though so will post another question on that (to avoid derailing this thread). Thanks a lot!!